# How do I set the Id of an entity if the entity inherits from a base class?

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-core, key

I have the following structure:

```
public class EntityBase {
    public Guid? Id { get;set; }
    public Guid? TheRealId {get;set;}
}

public class SomeInheritEntity : EntityBase {
    string SomeOtherProp {get;set;}
}
```

EFCore insists that the real ID is `Id` in the `SomeInheriteEntity`.  Since I this is an adapter, and I can't reliably count on Id to be truly unique, I've added another Id that I am going to ensure is unique.

How do I get EFcore to use `TheRealId` as the Id for all derived types of
`EntityBase`?

Edit:
I would like to avoid the pattern of assigning all of the `.HasKey` or the like in the Model Builder.  Maybe there is a decorator for the base class I can use?

I attempted to add `[Key]` to the base class `TheRealId`, but efcore still insisted on using `id` as the key when doing updates and checking for affecting 2 rows, meant to affect 1 type of errors.

This works:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<SomeInheritEntity>().HasKey("TheRealId");
}
```

But i would be declaring this for tons of inherit entities

Comment: If you use ```[Key]``` attribute on top of ```public Guid? TheRealId {get;set;}``` ?

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure `EntityBase` and then every derived type configure to set `EntityBase` as base type.

I would suggest using HasKey method overload with expression, instead of string. That should solve int/Guid issue.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<EntityBase>().HasKey(e => e.RealId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<SomeInheritEntity>().HasBaseType<EntityBase>();
    ...
}
```

[EntityTypeBuilder.HasBaseType Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder-1.hasbasetype?view=efcore-6.0)

[EntityTypeBuilder.HasKey Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder-1.haskey?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-builders-entitytypebuilder-1-haskey(system-linq-expressions-expression((system-func((-0-system-object))))))

[EF Core Inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance)